# How to Obtain the Chinese character stroke order from the ttf file?

Tags: java, swing, fonts

i find `getGlyphOutline()` can show font out line from JAVA API.
and i have not found out any API for show one chinese stroke order.
but this is true: **.ttf** contain the stroke order.
i just don't know how to get it by JAVA.

May be some important APIs i forget?

```
shape = gv.getGlyphOutline(i, 200, 200);
            ((Graphics2D) g).draw(shape);
```

---

now, i found PathIterator

```
Shape shape = gv.getGlyphOutline(0, 200, 200);
        PathIterator pi = shape.getPathIterator(new AffineTransform());
        double[] coords = new double[6];
        int count = 0;
        while (!pi.isDone()) {
            int kind = pi.currentSegment(coords);
            int[] path = new int[4];
            switch (kind) {
            case PathIterator.SEG_MOVETO:
                System.out.println("SEG_MOVETO");
                break;
            case PathIterator.SEG_LINETO:
                System.out.println("SEG_LINETO");
                break;
            case PathIterator.SEG_CLOSE:
                System.out.println("SEG_CLOSE");
                g.drawLine((int) coords[0], (int) coords[1],
                        (int) coords[2], (int) coords[3]);
                count++;
                break;
            case PathIterator.SEG_QUADTO:
                System.out.println("SEG_QUADTO");
                g.drawLine((int) coords[0], (int) coords[1],
                        (int) coords[2], (int) coords[3]);
                count++;
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad path segment");
            }
            pi.next();
        }
```

There is a problem, i can not get complete word..
It looks like dotted line...

Comment: The stroke order when writing Chinese is well defined http://www.archchinese.com/chinese_stroke_order_rules.html  Do you really need to look at a .ttf file to obtain it?

Comment: i already get order, but i just get the segement of stroke..looks like dotted line..

Comment: `case PathIterator.SEG_LINETO:` should have the action `g.drawLine((int) coords[0], (int) coords[1],
                        (int) coords[2], (int) coords[3]);` & `case PathIterator.SEG_QUADTO:` should be [`draw(Shape)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#draw-java.awt.Shape-) where the `Shape` is a [`QuadCurve2D`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/QuadCurve2D.html).  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (basically the same thing).

Comment: BTW - Do you mean 'stroke order' like as shown in the page for the [Kanji stroke order font v3.001](http://www.nihilist.org.uk/)?  I suspect that is one of the few TTF fonts that *does* store the stroke order.  Even then, beyond making the `GeneralPath` draw each stroke in turn (in the same order as the strokes), I do not believe a TTF even has the *capacity* to store a 'stroke order' in the sense you mean.

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean to draw the strokes of the characters 'part by part' - something like this code?

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.font.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class LettersByStrokeAnimation {

    private JComponent ui = null;
    String text = "";
    Font font;

    LettersByStrokeAnimation() {
        initUI();
    }

    public void initUI() {
        if (ui != null) {
            return;
        }

        ui = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));

        for (int i = 13444; i < 13450; i++) {
            text += new String(Character.toChars(i));
        }
        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        Font[] fonts = ge.getAllFonts();
        boolean canDisplay = false;
        int i = 0;
        while (!canDisplay) {
            font = fonts[i];
            if (font.canDisplayUpTo(text) < 0) {
                canDisplay = true;
                font = font.deriveFont(50f);
            }
            i++;
        }
        JLabel l = new JLabel(text);
        l.setFont(font);
        ui.add(l);

        ui.add(new AnimatedText(text, font, 200));
    }

    public JComponent getUI() {
        return ui;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception useDefault) {
                }
                LettersByStrokeAnimation o = new LettersByStrokeAnimation();

                JFrame f = new JFrame(o.getClass().getSimpleName());
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                f.setContentPane(o.getUI());
                f.pack();
                f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());

                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}

class AnimatedText extends JPanel {

    Font font;
    int counter;
    ArrayList<Shape> shapes;

    AnimatedText(String text, Font font, int delay) {
        this.font = font;
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g = bi.createGraphics();
        g.dispose();
        FontRenderContext frc = g.getFontRenderContext();
        GlyphVector gv = font.createGlyphVector(frc, text);
        Shape shape = gv.getOutline(0, 50);
        GeneralPath gp = new GeneralPath(shape);

        PathIterator pi = gp.getPathIterator(null);
        shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();
        while (!pi.isDone()) {
            shapes.add(getNextStroke(pi));
        }
        ActionListener timerListener = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                AnimatedText.this.repaint();
            }
        };
        Timer timer = new Timer(delay, timerListener);
        timer.start();
    }

    private final Shape getNextStroke(PathIterator pi) {
        double[] coords = new double[6];

        GeneralPath gp = new GeneralPath();
        boolean closed = false;
        while (!closed && !pi.isDone()) {
            int pathSegmentType = pi.currentSegment(coords);
            closed = pathSegmentType == PathIterator.SEG_CLOSE;
            int windingRule = pi.getWindingRule();
            gp.setWindingRule(windingRule);
            if (pathSegmentType == PathIterator.SEG_MOVETO) {
                gp.moveTo(coords[0], coords[1]);
            } else if (pathSegmentType == PathIterator.SEG_LINETO) {
                gp.lineTo(coords[0], coords[1]);
            } else if (pathSegmentType == PathIterator.SEG_QUADTO) {
                gp.quadTo(coords[0], coords[1], coords[2], coords[3]);
            } else if (pathSegmentType == PathIterator.SEG_CUBICTO) {
                gp.curveTo(
                        coords[0], coords[1], coords[2],
                        coords[3], coords[4], coords[5]);
            } else if (pathSegmentType == PathIterator.SEG_CLOSE) {
                gp.closePath();
            } else {
                System.err.println("Unexpected value! " + pathSegmentType);
            }
            pi.next();
        }
        Shape shape = new Area(gp);

        return shape;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        int current = counter % shapes.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < current; i++) {
            g2.draw(shapes.get(i));
        }

        counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: The stroke order does not look right. The radicals are drawn last. Inner and outer boundaries of the same shape are sometimes rendered at completely different times. This looks more as if you are just breaking the final resulting polyline into smaller pieces. It does not have much in common with the actual stroke order. Nice animation anyway +1.

Comment: *"The stroke order does not look right."*  (chuckle) If the stroke order *had* been right, it would have been purely by accident (and implementation & font dependent).  I couldn't resist posting the code and animation to try pointing that out - but maybe I should have included it in plain words.  ;)

Comment: Do you know if something like this exists for Swift?

Comment: @Crashalot I have no idea. Why not ask the experts on Swift?