# Foreign language not read correct in SQL

Tags: sql, nvarchar, thai

I have raw file with entry in Thai language " Yamato-Esulon (Thailand) Co.,Ltd (โรง 1)' but when i put that on SQL table it changes to  'Yamato-Esulon (Thailand) Co.,Ltd (Ó╣éÓ©úÓ©ç 1)' . I'm using datatype nvarchar(MAX). Has someone come across this before and how can this be prevented?

Comment: please show your data structure

Comment: Data type is nvarchar(MAX)

Comment: I have Text file (Test.txt) with data 'Yamato-Esulon (Thailand) Co.,Ltd (โรง 2)', and trying to get that into sql using    CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTestTable (
    MyData NVARCHAR(MAX)
 )

 truncate table dbo.MyTestTable

 BULK INSERT dbo.MyTestTable
FROM 'F:\PhocasAsia\rawdata\Test.txt'
With (ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')   Output is : ´╗┐Yamato-Esulon (Thailand) Co.,Ltd (Ó╣éÓ©úÓ©ç 2)   .. I'M unable to keep the right character as they are getting changed to some raw data.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be due to the font that you are using. Only certain fonts will work for thai language, so fonts like arial and calibri simply won't work.

For Thai, the fonts that work are:
Dialog, DialogInput, Monospaced, Sansserif, Serif, Leewaldee, Leewaldee UI, Leewaldee UI Semilight, Lucida Sans, Lucida Sans Typewriter, Microsoft Sans Serif, and Tahoma

This holds true for almost any other language, so be sure that a certain font works for the language that you are using. You can check which fonts work through a [.jar file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5B9wDXIGw9leE1VYURuU1ZkZkk/view) that I found online relating to an [older post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31515674/swing-components-does-not-show-thai-characters).