Some languages ​are not displayed correctly in java swing
I'm writing a multilingual application. Created a demo:
public class SwingLang {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(230,500);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        String[] x = new String[7];
        //текст "Checking your configuration and account"
        x[0] = "ব্যবস্থা এবং একাউন্ট দেখা"; //Bengal
        x[1] = "తయారీ మరియు ఖాతా తనిఖీ"; //Telugu
        x[2] = "तयारी र खाता जाँच"; //Nepali
        x[3] = "සූදානම් වීම සහ ගිණුම පරීක්\u200Dෂාව"; //Sinhalese
        x[4] = "तैयारी और खाता जांच"; //Hindi
        x[5] = "தயாரிப்பு மற்றும் கணக்கு சரிபார்ப்பு"; //Tamil
        x[6] = "การเตรียมและตรวจสอบบัญชี"; //Thai

        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            JLabel label = new JLabel(x[i]);

            System.out.println(x[i]);
            panel.add(label);
        }

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

These languages ​​in the swing application on Windows 10 are displayed as squares and this is the main problem.
All these languages ​​are displayed correctly on Linux Ubuntu.
On Windows, the console output is also correct.
Tried to pass a string in unicode - the result is the same. It outputs to the console as expected, swing outputs squares.
Most of all, I am interested in what I, as a developer, can do with the code or its launch parameters, so as not to write instructions on what the user should do with his OS
I tried to substitute fonts through the Font class, but this did not help either. Although the idea of ​​​​using fonts is not very good, considering that Linux reads without them.
And also I tried to change the versions of Java Open JDK 17 to 21. Newer than 21 are not compatible with Lombok for me, so I remove this option too

It may just be that the default font used by Linux includes these characters, but the font used by Windows doesn't

I could display the first 6 using the Nirmala UI font, the last one can be displayed with Leelawadee UI or Tahoma -- to find the installed fonts that can display a given text:  GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(); for (Font font : ge.getAllFonts()) if (font.canDisplayUpTo(x[0]) == -1)  System.out.println(font.getFontName());

This is only a suggestion - and I very much doubt it will resolve your problem, but anyway... Instead of the actual character, try the unicode escape, for example instead of the [Bengali] character ঀ, use \u0980.

@Abra should be no difference, AFAIK the \u escapes are translated to raw input characters as first step of compilation (kind of before feeding the compiler) ((e.g. one reason for having \n instead of just \u000D - String test = "a\000D"; does not compile))

@greg-449 But in every other native app, the host OS goes through a succession of fonts until a glyph is found for every character. This inability to search through fonts is a flaw in Java Swing. JavaFX seems to suffer the same.

You call these "rare languages" - they're spoken by millions of people.

@k314159 Actually, a quick check of Wikipedia plus some math in Java shows about a billion people speak those “rare” languages, give or take overlaps in 2nd language populations. Quite disappointing that Swing cannot serve those populations properly.

(Based on this answer and comments mentioned by user85421 & Ivar https://stackoverflow.com/a/31515771/16037941)
Try using a logical font such as SANS_SERIF which should pull from one or more physical font sources to generate the correct output initially.
Next check to see which of those texts can be displayed on the user computer using a function run on startup based the code provided in user85421's comment. IF there are languages which can't be used as there is no available font for them, then I would also mention to the user in some type of aside/settings: "We can't display language X because your PC does not have the font installed" that or attempt to sub fonts in the case where the OS is windows or attempt to install a font or font(s) yourself on first startup you know would work, but that for me is a touch dicey and can by annoying (I have had to do this for programs run through WINE, its a pet-peeve)
To add some additional context: To my knowledge there is not alot you can do, some non-latin characters require a bit of config on to OS side. Best of luck
